Second bachelors needed to transition from math to engineering?
If I have a BA in math and want to transition to mechanical or electrical engineering graduate school, is it better for me to complete a second BS in MechE or EE and then apply to grad programs, or is it enough to take some undergraduate prerequisites and then apply to graduate programs in engineering? Does it look "credible" to have a math undergrad and engineering grad degree, or will people assume I am missing the fundamentals without the BS on my CV?

What do you envision studying in grad school and what applied math classes have you taken? Some subfields, e.g., controls or the theoretical end of fluid dynamics, are strongly aligned with mathematics; others, e.g., experimental material science, will be much more dependent on engineering principles and other domain knowledge.

Nobody really cares about your undergrad degree once you have a PhD (broadly speaking). The bigger issue is convincing an engineering PhD program to admit you. That will depend on their concentrations and your other courses (physics, chemistry, some engineering).

In which country or countries do you hope to study?

To expand on Buffy's comment, in countries with a "short" PhD programme, the natural route from a very  pure maths undergraduate course to an engineering PhD would be through an appropriate masters degree (in the UK, a taught MSc). It's unclear from your current question of this is an option you're discounting or haven't considered.
